# Perl Navigator extension not working out of the box in vscode

Tags: perl, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Perl and trying to get syntax checking, code navigation etc. to work in VS Code on my Mac. I have installed the [PerlNavigator](https://github.com/bscan/PerlNavigator) Extension but it doesn't seem to work out of the box as it should.

The code I'm testing with is exactly the same that they use in their example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Set:Scalar;

my $set = Set:Scalar->new();

$set->insert
```

I have no Syntax Highlighting, nor Code completion. Also the imported Scalar Package is not recognised. Am I missing something here? Do I have to Install any dependencies first?

I have installed Perl 5.30 on my machine.

Comment: Please consider reporting a bug on [Perl Navigator](https://github.com/bscan/PerlNavigator/issues) bug tracker as this is what they want in case it doesn't work "out of the box". It will help improving later users experience.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I opened an issue: https://github.com/bscan/PerlNavigator/issues/116

Comment: How did you name the file? I am surprised that you have no syntax highlighting...

Comment: I named the file "test.pl" as usual. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. You might want to add `#!/usr/bin/env perl` on top of the file maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check the Perl's installation path.

[README says](https://github.com/bscan/PerlNavigator#perl-paths):

> If you have a nonstandard install of Perl, please set the setting `perlnavigator.perlPath`. The subfolder `./lib` will be added to your path automatically. You can also add additional include paths that will be added to the perl search path (`@INC`) via perlnavigator`.includePaths`.

Obviously, it can be confusing for newcomers to claim that PerlNavigator work *"out of the box"* and mention afterward that the path require to be set in configuration.

Comment: I red this section. My file is not in subfolder "./lib" but in root path so i changed perlnavigator.perlPath to "./" . I also tried using "/" and "." but it didnt work either. If i understand correctly with perlnavigator.includePaths set to ["$workspaceFolder"] the whole project should be included. But that doesnt change anything for me as it seems

Comment: `perlPath` must point to Perl's installation directory, and preferably be an absolute path. In my system, this is something like `/home/smonff/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.35.8/`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!! I found my perl installation on my system with `which -a perl` and set perlPath according to that: `"perlnavigator.perlPath": "/usr/bin/perl"`

Comment: This made perl navigator working. Maybe the setting instruction fo perlPath should be placed more prominent and specific in the Extension Guide. 
Thanks alot for your fast reply @smonff

Comment: Cool. Please mark the answer as *"Resolved"* / *"Accepted"* if it solved your issue @F.G.

Comment: This is surprising to me that `perlPath` fixed it. On linux, it finds `perl` by default. Perhaps something is different on MacOS that is preventing it from finding the system `perl`? @F.G., did you get syntax highlighting working while the Navigator was still failing to find a valid perl?

Comment: No, it didnt work for me at all until I set `perlPath`.